# C# targetting ARM: How to deserialize JSON?

Tags: c#, json, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I'm writing my first C# application for Windows 10 IoT.  I've got everything working, my web requests, etc and I am able to retrieve my desired content to render to the user.  But...it's in JSON and I can't seem it into a regular variable so that I can pick just one property.

```
JSON Result
{  
   "date":"2017-07-09",
   "period":"year",
   "views":970347,
   "visitors":150013,
   "likes":136,
   "reblogs":13,
   "comments":1099,
   "followers":145
}
```

I tried to add the Nuget package for NewtonSoft JSON (JSON.NET) and that doesn't seem to work on the rPI's ARM CPU.  So I started to use the `Windows.Data.JSON.JsonObject` class instead.

I parse the JSON response for my app using `JSonObject.Parse()` with this line, and then when I debug, I see the following.

```
JsonObject meme = JsonObject.Parse(ResponseContent);
```

[image]

I can see all of the values I want right there under meme. JSonObject offers `GetNamedString()` and `GetNamedObject()` methods but I get terminating errors for both with: `{"A method was called at an unexpected time.\r\n\r\nThis is not a string value. Use ValueType property to get the type."}`

I'm coming from PowerShell, where I would just dump the response in `$response` and pull out the key/value pair with `$Response.Views` but I've got no idea how this is supposed to work in c#.  What I really don't get is why it seems to stay in JSON after parsing it.

My goal is to assign the Followers and Visitors results from JSON to a variable so I can reference them later on.  The webrequest works...I just can't seem to get the JSON to Parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON on the Watch view is really just for display, but it's already in the type `JsonObject` as shown in the Type column.

It's saying that the method will not work because the type you are trying to extract cannot be handled by `GetNamedString()` and `GetNamedObject()`. You should have a `GetNamedValue()` method too which will handle the number:

```
meme.GetNamedValue("views").GetNumber()
```

You can also access the value through the index like this:

```
meme["views"].GetNumber()
```

If you want to make sure it doesn't fail for edge cases in terms of returned JSON values, you can use the `meme["whateverJSONkey"].ValueType` property and switch/case on that to prevent exceptions

Comment: This was the answer I needed!  I thought I could just call `meme.GetNamedValue("views")` and assign that to a variable, but adding `GetNumber()` was the magic ticket!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why JSON.NET didn't work, but the following compiles and executes just fine (async-ness left out for brevity):

```
string s = @"{  
  ""date"":""2017-07-09"",
  ""period"":""year"",
  ""views"":970347,
  ""visitors"":150013,
  ""likes"":136,
  ""reblogs"":13,
  ""comments"":1099,
  ""followers"":145
}";

JsonObject data = null;
if (!JsonObject.TryParse(s, out data))
  new MessageDialog("Not valid JSON").ShowAsync();

var followers = data["followers"].GetNumber();
var visitors = data["visitors"].GetNumber();

new MessageDialog(String.Format("You had {0} visitors and {1} followers",
  visitors, followers)).ShowAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you!  If the value I wanted to pull back was not a number, like `Period`, should I use G`etValue();` instead?

Comment: The type of elements in the collection are [`IJsonValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json.jsonvalue) so you would use the `GetString` method to retrieve a string.